# regular expression to get the domain name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I am having a problem with regular expression for getting the main domain name from a url. that is if i am having urls as given below..

```
http://domain.com/return/java.php?hello.asp
http://www.domain.com/return/java.php?hello.asp
http://blog.domain.net/return/java.php?hello.asp
http://us.blog.domain.co.us/return/java.php?hello.asp
http://domain.co.uk
http://domain.net
http://www.blog.domain.co.ca/return/java.php?hello.asp
http://us.domain.com/return/
```

from all this I should only get **domain** as the output of the regular expression..
so how do i do it?
i used;

```
var url = urls.match(/[^.]*.(com|net|org|info|coop|int|co\.uk|org\.uk|ac\.uk|uk)/g);
```

but it does not work for

```
  http://domain.net
```

so can someone help me out with this.

Comment: Domain may end by "/" or end-of-line, so "match(/[^.]*.(com|net|org|info|coop|int|co\.uk|org\.uk|ac\.uk|uk)(/|$)g)" may work.

Comment: Seems to be working, https://regex101.com/r/dL6nN7/2 and http://jsbin.com/zanivonijo/1/edit?js,console but I might be missing the point?

Comment: @Fumu7: what ever you gave is not working..

Comment: don't forget the escape signs for the `.` since it is a special character, after the `[^.]*` part. :)

Comment: @SusanWilliams did you find a solution, or do you still need some help. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `URL` rather than regex

```
var url  = new URL("http://domain.com/return/java.php?hello.asp");
console.log(url.hostname);
=> domain.com
```

**OR**

If you want the protocol as well

```
var url  = new URL("http://domain.com/return/java.php?hello.asp");
console.log(url.protocol+"//"+url.hostname);
= > http://domain.com
```

Comment: IE support is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

would this help ?

```
(http|https|ftp):\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9.])+/g
```

matches at

```
http://domain.com
http://www.domain.com
http://blog.domain.net
http://us.blog.domain.co.us
http://domain.co.uk
http://domain.net
http://www.blog.domain.co.ca
http://us.domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution changing the regex a bit:

```
url.match(/https?:\/\/[^/]+((?=\/)|$)/g);
//tested with Chrome 38+ on Win7
```

Basiclly checking for slash `/` or string end `$`

***Update replaced jsFiddle link with inline Stackoverflow-Code:***

```js
var urls = ['http://domain.com/return/java.php?hello.asp',
  'http://www.domain.com/return/java.php?hello.asp',
  'http://blog.domain.net/return/java.php?hello.asp',
  'http://us.blog.domain.co.us/return/java.php?hello.asp',
  'http://domain.co.uk',
  'http://domain.net',
  'http://www.blog.domain.co.ca/return/java.php?hello.asp',
  'http://us.domain.com/return/'
];

var htmlConsole = document.getElementById("result");
var htmlTab = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
var htmlNewLine = "<br />";

htmlConsole.innerHTML = "";
for (var id in urls) {

  htmlConsole.innerHTML += "URL: " + urls[id] + htmlNewLine;

  var matchResults = urls[id].match(/https?:\/\/[^/]+((?=\/)|$)/g);

  for (var innerIdx in matchResults) {
    htmlConsole.innerHTML += htmlTab + "MatchNumber: " + innerIdx + " MatchValue: " + matchResults[innerIdx] + htmlNewLine;
  }

  htmlConsole.innerHTML += htmlNewLine;

}
```

```html
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var url = urls.match(/[^./]*.(com|net|org|info|coop|int|co\.uk|co\.us|co\.ca|org\.uk|ac\.uk|uk)/g);
```

just added a `/` and updated the list of top-level domains to match your examples.
Although I do not recommend to keep the list of top-level domains within a regexp. it's just too many. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains